# Group items in xml, set width by percentage

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a login layout but I want all the items in the xml to be grouped so that they can be centered as if one item, and I want to set the editTexts to a percentage width instead of hardcoding it, this way it can fit better with different size screens.

I tried using layout_weight but for some reason it affected the height and not the width of the editTexts.

This is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#dedede"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_big" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/scardET"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:background="@drawable/selector_edittext"
        android:hint="Carnet"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordET"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:background="@drawable/selector_edittext"
        android:hint="Contraseña"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_button"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:text="entrar"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You need to use Constraint Layout to get width/height in percentages.**

These two lines of code will do the job for you.

```
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8"
app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
```

First line to allow you to set the width in percentage.
The second line will make sure that the percentage width is always respected by your view.

*Below is your code corrected to handle percentage width.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#dedede"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_big" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/scardET"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:background="@drawable/selector_edittext"
            android:hint="Carnet"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            android:text="" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordET"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/scardET"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:background="@drawable/selector_edittext"
            android:hint="Contraseña"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:text="" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_button"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:text="entrar"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create RelativeLayout inside your LinearLayout and set weights for it. Then add your `EditText` to the RelativeLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myLayout" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3">
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            //You can add Edit text here
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```